# merge or cbind using multiple columns as key in R

Tags: r, merge

I am using a toy exammple:

```
Data set A: 
color  number   valueA
red      18      0.2
blue     21      0.6
green    15      0.9
red      10      1.0
blue     11      2.1
green    13      3.6

Data set B: 
color  number   valueB
red      18      0.3
blue     21      0.5
green    15      0.1
red      10      1.1
blue     11      2.5
green    13      3.9
```

I want to be able to merge Dataset A and B; I will need to use color and number to create a unique key.
merge and cbind code that I have found seem to use a single primary key.
Can someone help me with 2 or more primary keys?
Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the output format you desire?

Answer (score 4):

```
merge(data1,data2)


# color number valueA valueB
# 1  blue     11    2.1    2.5
# 2  blue     21    0.6    0.5
# 3 green     13    3.6    3.9
# 4 green     15    0.9    0.1
# 5   red     10      1    1.1
# 6   red     18    0.2    0.3
```

Please also see documentation of `merge` function. Specifically `by`, `by.x` and `by.y` argument

> By default the data frames are merged on the columns with names they
>   both have, but separate specifications of the columns can be given by
>   **by.x** and **by.y.** The rows in the two data frames that match on the
>   specified columns are extracted, and joined together. If there is more
>   than one match, all possible matches contribute one row each. For the
>   precise meaning of ‘match’, see match.

Comment: I should have added, the rows are not necessarily ordered in exactly the same manner.  Would that change your response?  Thanks.

Comment: @user2892196 Doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to do this without sorting?